# TypeError: (0, _reactNativeScreens.useScreens) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I searched for this error but I didn't find solution.

```
TypeError: (0, _reactNativeScreens.useScreens) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNativeScreens.useScreens)()', '(0, _reactNativeScreens.useScreens)' is undefined)
 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

First I get this error
``` error: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-screens` from `node_modules\react-native-stack\src\NavigatorIos\index.js`: react-native-screens could not be found within the project.

````
After this error I installed
```npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view``` 

I am trying to run in android.
````

Answer (score 7):

Method `useScreens` is deprecated, please use `enableScreens` instead. Follow these steps:

**1. Install dependencies**

`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

Or just `expo install react-native-screens`

**2. Replace import**

Old: `import { useScreens } from 'react-native-screens';`

New: `import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';`

**3. Replace function**

Old: `useScreens();`

New: `enableScreens();`

*P.S. For any further info [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screens).*